# Using NetSuite custom records from C#

Tags: c#, netsuite

I have created custom data type in NetSuite called Webinar:
[image]

Now I would like to add new record from C# via NetSuite web service.:

```
    CustomRecord rec = new CustomRecord();
    RecordRef recType = new RecordRef();
    recType.internalId = "479"; // Internal ID of custom record type, not individual record id
    recType.type = RecordType.customRecord;
    recType.typeSpecified = true;
    rec.recType = recType;
    rec.name = "Webinar";
    CustomFieldRef[] customFieldArray = new CustomFieldRef[1];
    StringCustomFieldRef stringField = new StringCustomFieldRef();
    stringField.scriptId = "customrecord479";
    stringField.value = "A string";
    customFieldArray[0] = stringField;
    rec.customFieldList = customFieldArray;
    var addresponse = Service.add(rec);
```

During adding record I have error:

```
The specified custom field reference customrecord479 is invalid.
```

What is wrong and how to add record by using custom data types?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `customrecord479` is the script id for a record type but you're trying to use it for the script id of a custom field. Script id's for fields on custom records start with `custrecord`, not `customrecord`.

Also, in your screenshot, you show two custom fields that are of type 'Time of Day' and 'Date'.  In your code, you're trying to set the value for a `StringCustomFieldRef`. Try creating a `DateCustomFieldRef` instead and in the scriptId property use either 'custrecordcustrecord_webinar_time' or 'custrecordcustrecord_webinar_date' as you have shown in your screenshot.

You might also want to change the script id's for those fields so your not duplicating the 'custrecord' portion.